# Wrap Multiprocess Pool Inside Loop (Shared Memory Between Processes)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the Python package "deap" to solve some multiobjective optimization problems with genetic algorithms. The functions can be quite expensive, and because of the evolutionary nature of GA, it gets compounded pretty quick. Now this package *does* have some support to allow the evolutionary computations to be parallelized with multiprocess.

However, I'd like to go one step farther and run the optimization multiple times, with different values on some of the optimization parameters. For instance, I might want to solve the optimization problem with different values of the weights.

This seems like a pretty natural case for loops, but the problem is that these parameters must be defined in the global scope of the program (i.e., above the "main" function) so that all the sub-processes know about the parameters. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
# define deap parameters - have to be in the global scope
toolbox = base.Toolbox()
history = tools.History()
weights = [1, 1, -1] # This is primarily what I want to vary
creator.create("Fitness",base.Fitness, weights=weights)
creator.create("Individual", np.ndarray, fitness=creator.Fitness)

def main():
    # run GA to solve multiobjective optimization problem
    return my_optimized_values

if __name__=='__main__':
    ## What I'd like to do but can't ##
    ## all_weights =  list(itertools.product([1, -1],repeat=3))
    ## for combo in all_weights:
    ##     weights = combo
    ##
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    # This can be down here, and it distributes the GA computations to a pool of workers
    toolbox.register("map",pool.map) 
    my_values = main()
```

I've investigated various possibilities, like multiprocessing.Value, the pathos fork of multiprocessing, and others, but in the end there's always a problem with the child processes reading the Individual class.

I've posed this question on the deap users' group, but it's not nearly as big a community as SO. Plus, it seems to me that this is more of a general conceptual Python question than a specific issue with deap. My current solution to this problem is just to run the code multiple times and change some of the parameter definitions each time. At least this way the GA calculations are still parallelized, but it does require more manual intervention than I'd like.

Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `initializer`/`initargs` keyword arguments to [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) to pass different values for the global variables you need to change on each run. The `initializer` function will be called with `initargs` as its arguments for each worker process inside of your `Pool`, as soon as it starts up. You can set your global variables to the desired values there, and they'll be set properly inside each child for the lifetime of the pool.

You'll need to create a different `Pool` for each run, but that shouldn't be a problem:

```
toolbox = base.Toolbox()
history = tools.History()
weights = None # We'll set this in the children later.



def init(_weights):
    # This will run in each child process.
    global weights
    weights = _weights
    creator.create("Fitness",base.Fitness, weights=weights)
    creator.create("Individual", np.ndarray, fitness=creator.Fitness)


if __name__=='__main__':
    all_weights =  list(itertools.product([1, -1],repeat=3))
    for combo in all_weights:
        weights = combo
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6, initializer=init, initargs=(weights,))
        toolbox.register("map",pool.map) 
        my_values = main()
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast result. Here's my result: TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract <class 'deap.creator.Fitness'> with abstract attribute weights. The creator needs to have well-defined weights.

If I move all the creator stuff inside the "init" function (and add a corresponding global toolbox), then I get errors such as AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decorator', etc. The toolbox class has several "register" and "decorate" methods that are also inside the "init" function at this point (left out for brevity) that have to come after the toolbox = Toolbox() declaration.

Comment: @user3325401 ok, I just downloaded `deap` and got the example working (see the edit above). Without seeing your actual code, I don't know if it will work for you, though. The idea is to only set the values that depend on `weights` inside `init`, and do everything else in the parent process.

Comment: Thanks again. On second though, I think the issue is that the toolbox class registers some functions that are used in the GA process. For instance, up in the global scope I have something like this defined: "toolbox.register("population",tools.initRepeat,list,toolbox.individual)". Then down in the main function where I do all the GA stuff,  I actually draw from the population with the function "toolbox.population(n=numIndividuals)"
If I move the toolbox.register statements into the init function, then the error I get is "AttributeError: 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'population'".

Comment: @user3325401 Can you just keep making the `toolbox.register` calls in the parent process? Or do those rely on `weights` being set?

Comment: In a roundabout way, yes, they do rely on `weights` being set. The weights are required for the "Fitness" to be created, which is required for the "Individual" to be created, which is something that must be registered in the toolbox: `toolbox.register("individual",tools.initRepeat,creator.Individual,toolbox.indices,n=1)` and `toolbox.register("population",tools.initRepeat,list,toolbox.individual)`

Comment: @user3325401 Can you just create the `toolbox` in the parent's global scope (same place you had it originally), and then make the register calls inside `init`, then? If the parent needs access to the stuff you `register`, make them both inside the for loop after you set `weights = combo`, and then do it again in `init`.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been uncomfortable with DEAP's use of global scope, and I think I have an alternate solution for you.

It is possible to import a different version of each module per loop iteration, thereby avoiding any reliance on the global scope.

```
this_random = importlib.import_module("random")
this_creator = importlib.import_module("deap.creator")
this_algorithms = importlib.import_module("deap.algorithms")
this_base = importlib.import_module("deap.base")
this_tools = importlib.import_module("deap.tools")
```

As far as I can tell, this seems to play with multiprocessing.

As an example, here is a version of DEAP's onemax_mp.py that avoids putting any of the DEAP files in the global scope. I've included a loop in `__main__` that changes the weights per iteration. (It maximizes the number of ones the first time, and minimizes it the second time.) Everything works fine with multiprocessing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#    This file is part of DEAP.
#
#    DEAP is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
#    published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
#    the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#    DEAP is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
#    GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#    License along with DEAP. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import array
import multiprocessing
import sys

if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    print("mpga_onemax example requires Python >= 2.7.")
    exit(1)

import numpy
import importlib


def evalOneMax(individual):
    return sum(individual),


def do_onemax_mp(weights, random_seed=None):
    """ Run the onemax problem with the given weights and random seed. """

    # create local copies of each module
    this_random = importlib.import_module("random")
    this_creator = importlib.import_module("deap.creator")
    this_algorithms = importlib.import_module("deap.algorithms")
    this_base = importlib.import_module("deap.base")
    this_tools = importlib.import_module("deap.tools")

    # hoisted from global scope
    this_creator.create("FitnessMax", this_base.Fitness, weights=weights)
    this_creator.create("Individual", array.array, typecode='b',
                        fitness=this_creator.FitnessMax)
    this_toolbox = this_base.Toolbox()
    this_toolbox.register("attr_bool", this_random.randint, 0, 1)
    this_toolbox.register("individual", this_tools.initRepeat,
                          this_creator.Individual, this_toolbox.attr_bool, 100)
    this_toolbox.register("population", this_tools.initRepeat, list,
                          this_toolbox.individual)
    this_toolbox.register("evaluate", evalOneMax)
    this_toolbox.register("mate", this_tools.cxTwoPoint)
    this_toolbox.register("mutate", this_tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)
    this_toolbox.register("select", this_tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)

    # hoisted from __main__
    this_random.seed(random_seed)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    this_toolbox.register("map", pool.map)
    pop = this_toolbox.population(n=300)
    hof = this_tools.HallOfFame(1)
    this_stats = this_tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    this_stats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    this_stats.register("std", numpy.std)
    this_stats.register("min", numpy.min)
    this_stats.register("max", numpy.max)

    this_algorithms.eaSimple(pop, this_toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.2, ngen=40,
                             stats=this_stats, halloffame=hof)

    pool.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for tgt_weights in ((1.0,), (-1.0,)):
        do_onemax_mp(tgt_weights)
```